# How to avoid the shrinkage of the output merged pdf file using gs?

Tags: linux, bash, ghostscript

I use this command link to merge bunch of ps file and convert them to pdf in linux but the size of output pdf file shrinks from page 2 and almost vanishes by the last page.

```
gs  -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.rg=4.0*.ps
```

Any tips what could cause the problem and how could it get fixed?

Comment: Most likely each PostScript program is not self-contained. It probably modifies the CTM and this causes the next page to inherit the CTM of the prior one which it then modifies further, and so on. This means firstly that your PostScript programs are badly behaved. You can eliminate this by encapsulating each one in with a 'save' before each program and a 'restore' after each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert each ps file into pdf separately.

```
i=1
ls *4.0*.ps |while read line
do
  gs  -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=new.${i}.pdf ${line}
  i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Then use pdftk-server (http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) to merge all pdf files into one pdf.

```
pdftk new.*.pdf output output.pdf
```

Comment: I tried your answer and I get this error message:                Error: Handle can only be a single, upper-case letter

Comment: en, the command pdftk only accepts the file name start with uppercase or lowercase. I updated the answer, can you try again?